# Remove all files not working with "*"

Tags: linux, remove

I want to remove all files and folders in folder /home/user
I'm using command

```
rm -rf /home/user/*
```

without success, next I tried:

```
cd /home/user;rm -rf *
```

Which gives the following output

```
rm: cannot lstat `*': No such file or directory
```

How do I solve that? If I'm deleting file one by one, it works, but with "*" it does not.

Comment: Why isn't the first command working? What error are you getting?

Comment: it does nothing, files still in place

Answer (score 1):

Does your user have read access to the files you want to remove? What are the filenames like? If they begin with a `.` they *may* not be picked up by the `*`.

To delete files starting with `.` in the current directory, you can use the old trick of `find` piped to `xargs`:

```
find . -name '.*' -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs rm
```

Try first without the `| xargs rm` to see if the files returned by `find` match what you expect, then run it again with the pipe.

If you want to also look for files recursively, just take the `-maxdepth 1` out of the command.

Comment: they are starting with ".". how delete files starting with "."?

Comment: Advice: Do *NOT* try `rm -rf .*`. Depending on your config, this may match "..", ie upwards in the directory structure.

Comment: solution, i don`t know if is it kind of right, but it works:ls -a | xargs rm -rf

Comment: For the same reason, if you use that solution, you might want to make that `ls -A | xargs rm -rf` (captial A is "all files, except '.' and '..').

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
find /home/user -delete
```

But be careful - read the man page for find first! Or train a bit in a particular directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just use `rm -rf /home/user`.